# How can I install Windows XP after Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, unetbootin, startup-disk-creator

I want to install Windows XP alongside Ubuntu for gaming but startup disk creator doesn't work.

I tried unetbootin but can't figure out how to format my USB to FAT32.

It's ok if I have to install Ubuntu again after installing Windows.

Comment: Windows XP is EOL !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) and [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Download a program called etcher at "etcher.io". Then,choose the iso you want to burn, insert your flashdrive or disk, and hit flash. Once this is done, figure out how to enter setup mode on your computer, and change the boot order to external drive first, optical drive second, and hard disk last. This will make the computer check for an OS in the flash drive first. then it will run it. Download the software and then setup the partitions (half and half) and go on your way.